# How NDB writes are counted?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If I add the same data to the datastore second time, will it require additional write operations?

For example, I have the following class:

```
class Song(ndb.Model):
    artist = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True, indexed=False)
```

and the following code to add new song there or update existing values:

```
def add_song(artist, title):
    song_id = artist+ ' - ' + title
    record = Song.get_by_id(song_id)
    if not record:
        record = Song(id=song_id)
    record.artist = artist
    record.title = title
    record.put()
```

Will it work efficiently? I.e. will not write artist and title values, if they are already there and the same? Or, should I optimize the code like below:

```
def add_song(artist, title):
    song_id = artist+ ' - ' + title
    record = Song.get_by_id(song_id)
    if not record:
        record = Song(id=song_id)
    if record.artist != artist: # new line!
        record.artist = artist
    if record.title != title: # new line!
        record.title = title
    if record.artist != artist or record.title != title: # new line!
        record.put()
```

Will these two codes generate the same number of write operations, when called:

```
add_song('Artist Name', 'Song Title')
add_song('Artist Name', 'Song Title') # same artist, same title - second addition
```

or

```
add_song('Artist Name', 'Song Title')
add_song('Artist Name', 'New Song Title') # same artist, new title - second addition
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should optimize -- you're just doing it wrong.

Specifically, you're checking `if record.artist != artist` &c) **after** your snippet

```
if record.artist != artist: # new line!
    record.artist = artist
```

which of course ensures the `!=` condition cannot persist.  Therefore, you will never reach the condition where you can call the `.put()`.

Try, rather, something like:

```
def add_song(artist, title):
    song_id = artist+ ' - ' + title
    record = Song.get_by_id(song_id)
    if record:
        if record.artist != artist or record.title != title: # new line!
            record.artist = artist
            record.title = title
            is_new = True
        else:
            is_new = False
    else:
        record = Song(id=song_id, artist=artist, title=title)
        is_new = True
    if is_new:
         record.put()
```

Comment: Thanks. What is wrong with my second code? In your code you would update both title and artist, when only the title is changed - is it correct approach?

Comment: @LA_, added the explanation: **first** you make sure `record.artist` equals `artist` (by assigning it if necessary), **then** you check if they're still different (which of course they won't be: your assignment just ensured that!) and since they aren't you don't call the `put`.  As for assigning both fields of `record` even in the case where only one need be, that's a trivial (nanosecond) in-memory operation -- I picked it just to try to simplify things a bit by keeping a single bool flag rather than two and maintaining it more symmetrically.

Comment: I see my mistake now, thanks. With regards to assigning both fields of `record` when only one is changed - will not it cause additional write operations what I am trying to avoid?

Comment: @LA_ no it won't, the one and only write operation occurs if and when `put` is called.

Comment: Are you sure? We are talking about NDB write ops, don't believe it is just one operation - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Understanding_write_costs

Comment: Yes, indices can also get updated, etc, etc, but reassigning an unchanged attribute before the `.put` call makes absolutely no difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, re-putting the exact same object will cause a write to the datastore.

Actually, a bit more than ONE write, depending on the indexes serving on your kind.

You might have a bit more info if you look at the [ndb doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/#storing) and [this article](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write)